# JEditorPane do not respect html table height 100%

Tags: java, html, swing

i have got a problem, my JEditorPane do not respect HTML-Table `style="height: 100%;"`
do you have an idea?

```
JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( jEditorPane );
jEditorPane.setPage( url );
JFrame frame = new JFrame( );
frame.getContentPane( ).add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
frame.setSize( 800, 600 );
frame.setVisible( true );


<html style="height: 100%;">
  <body style="height: 100%;">
  </head><body>
    <table style="height: 100%;width: 100%"  border="1">
       <tr><td>1</td><td>12</td></tr>
       <tr><td>2</td><td>22</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

[JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)'s HTML support is for [version 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32). HTML 3.2 [tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#table) do not have a `style` attribute.

Comment: Perhaps look at the Flying Saucer project for a Swing XHTML renderer